# Magento - Deleted Base url key

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, ftp

I was working on cleaning up my url:

http://mydomain.com/shop/shop/deals

I was going through my settings in the configuration tab in the admin panel on Magento and change my secure and unsecure base urls to remove the first base url "shop" so my web page would then read:

http://mydomain.com/shop/deals

So my i changed the unsecure base urls from mydomain.com/shop to mydomain.com and my secure from 12.345.67.89/shop to 12.345.67.89. Which was the wrong thing to do.

I now cannot reload the page or get to the admin console.

How could i access these files through FTP and change the correctly there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the changes in the admin panel the changes are made in the database not in any file. You will have to make the changes now in database.

1.Go to you Database and select the `core_config_data` table

1. Under this table find `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`. Make the changes here.

Don't forget to clear the cache in `var/cache` folder

Answer (score 0):

You're a little unclear on what

> Which was the wrong thing to do.

means, but those values are stored in the `core_config_data` table. Look for that row where the column `path` is equal to `web/unsecure/base_url` or `web/secure/base_url`.  You can change the values back there.  Once you've done that, clear your cache (remove all the folders in `var/cache/*`, and you should be good to go.